# Python Tkinter: Sharing an asyncio event loop with Telemetrix-AIO

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-asyncio, esp32

I'm using the Python Telemetrix library for controlling an ESP32. I've got a Tkinter application with an interface, and I'd like to connect and disconnect while the application is running so I can change which microcontroller I'm addressing.

Dev Environment:

- Windows 11
- Python 3.11.5

This blink example works correctly for me. It successfully connects and blinks the LED

Blink Example: https://github.com/MrYsLab/telemetrix-esp32/blob/master/examples/wifi-aio/blink_wifi_aio.py

Here is my own example code to demonstrate how my application is using asyncio and the problem I'm having using the Telemetrix module. I wanted to use pure asyncio so there is no use of the threading module.

```
import asyncio
import tkinter as tk
from telemetrix_aio_esp32 import telemetrix_aio_esp32

DIGITAL_PIN = 2

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("TelemetrixAioEsp32 Blink Example")

        self.board = None

        self.ip_address_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.ip_address_frame.pack()

        self.ip_address_label = tk.Label(self.ip_address_frame, text="IP Address:")
        self.ip_address_label.pack(side="left")

        self.ip_address_entry = tk.Entry(self.ip_address_frame)
        self.ip_address_entry.pack(side="left", padx=5)
        self.ip_address_entry.insert("end",'192.168.1.196')  

        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.button_frame.pack()

        self.connect_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Connect", command=self.start_connect)
        self.connect_button.pack(side="left", padx=5)

        self.start_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Start Blink", command=self.start_blink)
        self.start_button.pack(side="left")
        self.start_button['state'] = tk.DISABLED

        self.request_blink = False
        self.request_connect = False

        self.event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.event_loop)

        self.showing = True

        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

    async def connect(self):
        if self.board is None:
            ip_address = self.ip_address_entry.get()
            self.board = telemetrix_aio_esp32.TelemetrixAioEsp32(transport_address=ip_address, loop=self.event_loop, autostart=False)
            await self.board.start_aio()

            self.connect_button["text"] = "Disconnect"
            self.start_button['state'] = tk.NORMAL
        else:

            await self.board.shutdown()

            self.board = None
            self.connect_button["text"] = "Connect"
            self.start_button['state'] = tk.DISABLED

    async def show(self):
        while self.showing:
            self.root.update()

            if self.request_blink:
                self.request_blink = False
                await self.blink(DIGITAL_PIN)
            if self.request_connect:
                self.request_connect = False
                await self.connect()

        if self.board is not None:
            await self.connect() 

    async def blink(self, pin):
        try:
            await self.board.set_pin_mode_digital_output(pin)

            for x in range(4):
                print('ON')
                await self.board.digital_write(pin, 0)
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                print('OFF')
                await self.board.digital_write(pin, 1)
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error during blink: {e}")

    def start_blink(self):
        self.request_blink = True

    def start_connect(self):
        self.request_connect = True

    async def run_tk(self):
        try:
            await self.show();
        finally:
            self.event_loop.close()

    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self.run_tk())

    def on_closing(self):
        self.showing = False
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

I'm running my own event loop using asyncio to handle updating the tkwindow, as well as any async methods I might need to run depending on what the user selects. This has worked well with the websockets library for starting and stopping a websocket connection.

However the above example code produces the following error when it connects to the ESP32

```
PS C:\Users\lokno\Desktop\Scratch\Code> python .\blink_wifi_app.py
TelemetrixAioEsp32 Version: 1.3
Copyright (c) 2022 Alan Yorinks All rights reserved.

Successfully connected to: 192.168.1.196:31336
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lokno\Desktop\Scratch\Code\blink_wifi_app.py", line 110, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Users\lokno\Desktop\Scratch\Code\blink_wifi_app.py", line 102, in run
    asyncio.run(self.run_tk())
  File "C:\Users\lokno\scoop\apps\python\current\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lokno\scoop\apps\python\current\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lokno\scoop\apps\python\current\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lokno\Desktop\Scratch\Code\blink_wifi_app.py", line 97, in run_tk
    await self.show();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lokno\Desktop\Scratch\Code\blink_wifi_app.py", line 69, in show
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\lokno\Desktop\Scratch\Code\blink_wifi_app.py", line 48, in connect
    await self.board.start_aio()
  File "C:\Users\lokno\scoop\apps\python\current\Lib\site-packages\telemetrix_aio_esp32\telemetrix_aio_esp32.py", line 282, in start_aio
    raise RuntimeError('Could not retrieve server firmware version')
RuntimeError: Could not retrieve server firmware version
```

I believe there's a mistake with how I'm using asyncio along with the telemetrix library. I'm sending in my own event loop and setting autostart=False which just runs the following line:

```
if autostart:
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start_aio())
```

The current error is unhelpful and I'm stuck. It suggests something is wrong with how I'm running start_aio(), but I'm not sure what exactly. I appreciate any debugging advice.

The Telemetrix library has no open issues.

Here is the main module I'm importing:
https://github.com/MrYsLab/telemetrix-esp32/blob/master/telemetrix_aio_esp32/telemetrix_aio_esp32.py

The actual application I'm developing is located here:
https://github.com/Lokno/ArduinoControlUtilities/blob/main/websocket_pyfirmata.py

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. I did not realize that the convenience method asyncio.run() was itself creating an event loop. I thought it might have used the previous set event loop since I called asyncio.set_event_loop() earlier. So the loop I sent into the TelemetrixAioEsp32 constructor was not the same loop running the connect method.

Corrected code, now with a button to blink the LED.

```
import asyncio
import tkinter as tk
from telemetrix_aio_esp32 import telemetrix_aio_esp32

DIGITAL_PIN = 2

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("TelemetrixAioEsp32 Blink Example")

        self.board = None

        self.ip_address_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.ip_address_frame.pack()

        self.ip_address_label = tk.Label(self.ip_address_frame, text="IP Address:")
        self.ip_address_label.pack(side="left")

        self.ip_address_entry = tk.Entry(self.ip_address_frame)
        self.ip_address_entry.pack(side="left", padx=5)
        self.ip_address_entry.insert("end",'192.168.1.196')  

        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.button_frame.pack()

        self.connect_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Connect", command=self.start_connect)
        self.connect_button.pack(side="left", padx=5)

        self.start_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="On", command=self.start_blink)
        self.start_button.pack(side="left")
        self.start_button['state'] = tk.DISABLED

        self.request_blink = False
        self.request_connect = False

        self.event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.event_loop)

        self.showing = True

        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

        self.led_on = False

    async def connect(self):
        if self.board is None:
            ip_address = self.ip_address_entry.get()
            self.board = telemetrix_aio_esp32.TelemetrixAioEsp32(transport_address=ip_address, loop=self.event_loop, autostart=False)
            await self.board.start_aio()

            await self.board.set_pin_mode_digital_output(DIGITAL_PIN)
            await self.board.digital_write(DIGITAL_PIN, 0)

            self.led_on = False
            self.start_button["text"] = "On"
            self.connect_button["text"] = "Disconnect"
            self.start_button['state'] = tk.NORMAL
        else:
            await self.board.shutdown()
            self.board = None

            if self.showing:
                self.connect_button["text"] = "Connect"
                self.start_button['state'] = tk.DISABLED

        if self.showing:
            self.connect_button['state'] = tk.NORMAL

    async def show(self):
        while self.showing:
            self.root.update()

            if self.request_blink:
                self.request_blink = False
                if self.led_on:
                    await self.board.digital_write(DIGITAL_PIN, 0)
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
                    self.start_button["text"] = "On"
                    self.led_on = False
                else:
                    await self.board.digital_write(DIGITAL_PIN, 1)
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
                    self.start_button["text"] = "Off"
                    self.led_on = True  
                self.start_button['state'] = tk.NORMAL          
            if self.request_connect:
                self.request_connect = False
                await self.connect()

        if self.board is not None:
            await self.connect() 

    def start_blink(self):
        self.request_blink = True
        self.start_button['state'] = tk.DISABLED

    def start_connect(self):
        self.request_connect = True
        self.connect_button['state'] = tk.DISABLED

    def run(self):
        self.event_loop.run_until_complete(self.show())

    def on_closing(self):
        self.showing = False
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run()
```